# Problems with Date to Timestamp results

Tags: php, wordpress, timestamp, strtotime

I read thru as many similar posts relating to dates and timestamps and couldn't find a solution so I hope this is a simple as I think it should be....

I have dates that are getting posted to a Wordpress database via custom fields, currently in the format of yymmdd.  I have some code to convert those dates to timestamps so that I can do something with posts that have timestamps greater than today's date, and something different with posts having timestamps less than today's date.  But I'm not getting all the posts.

Here's my code to get the metadata and convert it:

```
query_posts('post_type=deal&meta_key=booking_date_end&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1'); 
if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

$now = time('now');
$exp_date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'booking_date_end',true);
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);
$today = strtotime($now); 

if ($today <= $expiration_date) {
```

From here it displays a list of those posts (deals) that are not 'expired'.  The same code is repeated below that with the comparison operator set to greater than the expiration dates and is supposed to list those posts (deals) that *have* expired.

In the first instance I do get some posts, but not all, that aren't expired...I'm baffled as to why it picks up some but not all.  In the second instance it lists no posts, even though there are several that are expired.

If necessary I can change the way that the dates are stored in the database. In theory what I have should work, but doesn't.

Comment: Generally is a bad idea to use `query_posts`, check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615).

Comment: I did read that and I do understand it, but this particular code is on a page with several other queries, and I was trying to keep the workload down on the server....I could change that to get_posts, I think, and accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Yes, always use get_posts or wp_query if you want to have more custom query.

Comment: I swapped out query_posts for get_posts, but it made no difference in my odd results....upon closer inspection of what it is returning, I get posts that are both  before and after the expiration date returned in the first instance, no posts in the second.....so I still think something is wrong with how it's converting the stored date to a timestamp in order to compare it to todays' date.

Comment: Since what I'm trying to accomplish is to compare the date stored as metadata with the current date in order to do something, am I better off to use DateTime::Diff, or DateInterval?  Basically we have posts that are "deals" and using custom fields to store the date that the deal expires.  I need to be able to show non-expired deals at the top of the page and expired deals below that.  Anyone?